# Spring boot - MasterReplicaTopologyRefresh - Unable to connect to 172.21.0.3:6379

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I'm using Spring Boot to connect to Redis, every time I try to write into Redis I got this error MasterReplicaTopologyRefresh - Unable to connect to 172.21.0.3:6379, it's trying to contact the wrong server several times it sends 4 requests after 4 seconds.
Is there a way to stop or override the default host and port?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from readFrom(ReadFrom.MASTER) after removing it, it worked fine, when it is enabled the connection config keeps try to connect to the master

```
LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            //.readFrom(ReadFrom.MASTER)
            .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
            .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions)
            .build();
```